# Packages "LibertinusT1Math" raises error if compiled with XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, unicode-math, libertinus

The following MWE raises an error if compiled with XeLaTex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertinus}
\usepackage[slantedGreek]{libertinust1math}

\begin{document}
Lore ipsum dulur.
\end{document}
```

The error is:

```
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)

! LaTeX Error: Command \dddot already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

The [LibertineT1Math documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/libertinust1math/doc/LibertinusT1Math-doc.pdf) says that it loads "amsmath", if required, but this obviously results into an error.

How do I use the font Libertine/Libertinus not only for the text body, but also vor mathematical material, together with XeLaTeX?

Comment: the libertinus package loads unicode-math and setups an unicode-math font. This clashes with libertinus1math.

Comment: In my opinion, the `nomath` option should avoid the loading of `unicode-math`.

Answer (score 5):

The `libertinus` package (actually `libertinus-otf`, that's loaded when XeLaTeX is used) has a `nomath` option, which however doesn't avoid loading `unicode-math`, but just doesn't set Libertinus Math as the math font.

In my opinion the package should offer the option of using legacy math fonts such as Libertinus1Math.

Workaround: trick LaTeX into thinking that `unicode-math` has already been loaded; you also need to explicitly load `fontspec`.

```latex
\expandafter\def\csname ver@unicode-math.sty\endcsname{}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[nomath]{libertinus}
\usepackage[slantedGreek]{libertinust1math}

\begin{document}
Lore ipsum dulur $a=b-\sin x$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the output of `pdffonts`:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
HXAFGM+LibertinusSerif-Regular-Identity-H CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      5  0
XWISZM+LibertinusT1Math              Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes      6  0
RZKIRB+LibertinusT1Math              Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes      7  0
```

If you're happy to use `unicode-math`, then you can use the ISO math style:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{math-style=ISO}{unicode-math}
\usepackage{libertinus}

\begin{document}
Lore ipsum dulur $a=b-\sin 2x$

$\Gamma$ $\Delta$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I do not mind to not use `libertinust1math` and use the "pure" `libertinus-otf` package that also sets the correct font family for math, if compiled with XeLaTeX. But I am missing a similar option for "slantedGreek". Is this not implemented or do I miss something?

Comment: @nagmat84 No, it's not implemented, but there's a workaround.